# pysnmp get subtree and do not resolve oid against mib name

Tags: python, python-2.7, snmp, pysnmp

I want to provide pysnmp with a base oid for example `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8` and be able to get all it's children underneath it e.g `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.1 - 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.n` without going over to `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9`.  I was wondering how I would go about this?  I have also tried doing a GETNEXT but not sure how to go about achieving what I want.  Another question is pysnmp seems to try to resolve the oid to the mib associated with it, how do I go about turning this feature off?  I am currently using the latest version of pysnmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing both [lookupMib=False](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#waive-mib-lookup) and [lexicographicMode=False](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/table-operations.html#fetch-whole-snmp-table) to nextCmd() or bulkCmd():

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for errorIndication, errorStatus, \
    errorIndex, varBinds in bulkCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public'),
        UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
        ContextData(),
        0, 50,  # GETBULK specific: request up to 50 OIDs in a single response
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8')),
        lookupMib=False, lexicographicMode=False):

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
        break
    elif errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1][0] or '?'))
        break
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```